# Create rule-based renderer from an existing renderer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, symbology, rule-based

I want to make a copy from an existing layer in the legend and render it with a rule-based renderer based on the original layer's graduated symbol renderer. Then I will change its rule expressions, clone all the rules (if that is even possible) and change again their expressions.

Right now I'm at step one: creating a rule-based renderer from an existing graduated symbol renderer.
With iface.actionDuplicateLayer().trigger() I clone the original layer with its renderer. Then I use convertFromRenderer function to create a QgsRuleBasedRendererV2 from the new layer's graduated symbol renderer and I assign it to the layer. But there's something I'm doing wrong because QGIS crashes at this point and I can't find the reason.

```
# Duplicate original layer
for layer in iface.legendInterface().layers():
    if layer.name() == 'Lines':
        iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        iface.actionDuplicateLayer().trigger()
# Make the new layer visible and change its name
for layer in iface.legendInterface().layers():
    if layer.name() == 'Lines copy':
        vl = layer
iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(vl, True)
vl.setLayerName('Lines - Atlas')

# Create rule-based renderer from its graduated symbol renderer
#  and assign it to it
renderer  = vl.rendererV2()
if renderer.type() == 'graduatedSymbol':
    rSimbol = renderer.sourceSymbol()
    ruleRend = QgsRuleBasedRendererV2(rSimbol).convertFromRenderer(renderer)
    vl.setRendererV2(ruleRend) #<------- QGIS crashes here
    iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(vl)

#Refresh canvas
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.refresh()
```

Comment: Does that work better? `QgsRuleBasedRendererV2.convertFromRenderer(renderer)`

Comment: Thank you so much @MatthiasKuhn. That has sense. There is no need to provide a default symbol to the renderer since it will take everything from the original renderer. I don't know why I discarded that possibility.

Comment: Great, turned it into an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convertFromRenderer is a static function and therefore does not need an instance to work on.

You can simply use the following:

```
if renderer.type() == 'graduatedSymbol':
    ruleRend = QgsRuleBasedRendererV2.convertFromRenderer(renderer)
    ...
```